пишет ошибку: Unresolved reference: nav_host_fragment_activity_main
пишет ошибку:

Unresolved reference: nav_host_fragment_activity_main

хотя код как и при создании Bootom Navigation Views Activity шаблона такой же код у меня
и вдруг стал писать ошибку
вот мой код:
package com.example.spektr

import android.R
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.spektr.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  //  private   ActivityMainBinding binding;
  //val   URL: String
  private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

      private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

          override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
              if (Uri.parse(url).host == "www.example.com") {
                  // This is your website, so don't override. Let your WebView load
                  // the page.
                  return false
              }
              // Otherwise, the link isn't for a page on your site, so launch another
              // Activity that handles URLs.
              Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
                  startActivity(this)
              }
              return true
          }
      }


  }


   private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
   // var  URL = "https://spektr-ekb.ru";
  // val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.WebView)
   // myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        //navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(HomeViewModel)
     //   navView.setOnItemSelectedListener(HomeViewModel) {
     //       val myWebView: WebView = binding.WebView
     //       myWebView.loadUrl("https://spektr-ekb.ru/")
      //  }

        val myWebView: WebView = binding.WebView
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://spektr-ekb.ru")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        //myWebView.settings.setW
       // myWebView.webViewClient

       // val myWebView: WebView = binding.WebView
        myWebView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
   }
}

private fun Intent.startActivity(intent: Intent) {

}

То есть в лайауте есть activity_main.xml и  в моем коде как и в шаблоне есть фрагмент с ИД : nav_host_fragment_activity_main
Но при этом: в mail_activity.kt через R.id он не находится!!!!!!
А в только что созданном шаблоне находится!!!!
Как так?

Также и такой код не дает обратиться к элементам меню
NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener {    item ->
            when(item.itemId) {
                R.id.item_1 -> {
                    // Respond to navigation item 1 click
                    true
                }
                R.id.item_2 -> {
                    // Respond to navigation item 2 click
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

и item подсвечивается красным

просто удалил import android.R
